# Bulk set in redis cache

Tags: caching, redis, jedis, redis-cache

I'm using Redis as a cache for my application layer.As it's a java application so I'm taking the advantage of Jedis client. Using this I was able to do all basic operation like set, get and delete.

Is there a way to do bulk set(batch insertions) using Jedis client

```
Jedis client = new Jedis("localhost", 6379);
client.set("name", "abc");
client.get("name");
//didn't find any such method
client.setAll(map...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using `mset` command for bulk set. You can also use pipelined `set` command.